# Which truth table should I look at for this logic question?

Tags: logic

I have a question (please see the following question) as I am unable to get my head around it.. Either that or I may have confuse myself somewhere along the way while trying to compare the truth table. This is an exercise from my guide book..

> Use a truth table to determine whether or not the proposition (¬p→q)∧p
>   logically implies the proposition q→p

[image]

The answer in the guide book is stated as `Yes, (¬p→q)∧p⇒q→p`

So can I assume that for this questions, it is following the truth table of p→q where `p` is the output of `(¬p→q)∧p` where `q` is `q→p` because of the word - logically in the question? Or am I simply wrong?

Comment: That last statement of yours is extremely unclear IMO. The answer in the guide book says that it's true, your truth table shows that it's true, what more do you want?

Comment: $p$ alone implies $q\to p$. $p\to(q\to p)$ is often taken as an axiom of Hilbert-style deductive systems for propositional logic. Your truth table is correct and shows that the formula in the rightmost column is valid (a tautology).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show that a propositional statement, in your case $\neg p\rightarrow q\wedge p$ logically implies an other statement, in this case $q\rightarrow p$ you have to show that each time the first statement is true, the second statement is also true.

When you look at the truth table you see that $\neg p\rightarrow q\wedge p$ is true in the top most rows, while in the top two rows we also have that $q\rightarrow p$ is true. Thus $\neg p\rightarrow q\wedge p$ logically implies $q\rightarrow p$.

It does not matter that $q\rightarrow p$ is also true in the fourth row, as we only study the rows where the first statement is true, not the second. In this case the first statement, $\neg p\rightarrow q\wedge p$, has truth which is equivalent to that of $p$, but this is just a coincidence and should not be seen as a general rule when looking at logical implications.

Answer (score 1):

We have that:

> $\varphi$ *logically implies* $\psi$ **iff** $\varphi \to \psi$ is a *tautology*.

Thus, you have to chek **all** rows of the t-t for the formula:

> $((¬p→q)∧p) \to (q→p))$;

if all have $1$, the formula is a *tautology*.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what you mean but the question you were asked can be restated as:
Is $((\lnot p \rightarrow q) \land p) \rightarrow (q \rightarrow p)$ a tautology (meaning always true).

To do this, take each "part" and define its truth function as was done on the truth table.

Note that $a \rightarrow b$ is true whenever $a$ is false or $b$ is true. This is how the last column of your truth table was derived from the preceding two columns.

In other words, the sentence $((\lnot p \rightarrow q) \land p$ is never true when $q \rightarrow p$ is false, the whole statement is a tautology and always true.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

The implication $((\neg p\rightarrow q) \land p) \rightarrow (q \rightarrow p)$ is correct, beacause the "main implication column" of the statement is filled with ones.

[image: Truth Table]